# "A non-existent config entity name returned by FieldStorageConfigInterface::getBundles()" errors in watchdog

Tags: views, migrations, 9

After migrating from 7 to 9, I'm getting a lot of these errors in watchdog, from **views**.

> A non-existent config entity name returned by `FieldStorageConfigInterface::getBundles()`: entity type: `paragraph`, bundle: `iframe`, field name: `field_url`

Things I've tried:

- Checking paragraph bundles(types): there are only two, the iframe one does not exist (I don't need it in the new site).
- `drush cr`
- `drush config:export` then grepping the files for `iframe`: it only exists in `media.settings.yml` as `iframe_domain: ''` - not relevant
- grepping the config files for `field_url` - not found.
- maybe there's some old content referencing the `iframe` bundle? `select distinct type from paragraphs_item;` only shows the new bundle names. Same for `paragraphs_item_field_data`
- `show tables like "%field_url%";` This does reveal two tables: `paragraph__field_url` and `paragraph_revision__field_url` - I would have expected these to be deleted. They are both empty though.
- `show tables like "%iframe%";` - none.
- I've been through all the views - but these are all the default D9 ones, plus a few I've added myself for the new site, which do not have anything to do with paragraph bundles.
- I checked the fields-used-in-views report - `field_url` is not there.
- I checked the fields list report. `field_url` is there, and weirdly, it says the entity type is `paragraph` but then it says:

  > Text (plain) (module: core)
- I tried re-creating a paragraph type called iframe and then deleting it.
- I tried to add a field called url, but it is forbidden because that machine name already exists.

I'm stumped as to how to get rid of these errors/notices.

### Update

I found some config yml files that related to this URL field. I deleted those and did a config import, which seemed to clear the problem for that field, but opened it up for other fields.

It's now complaining about entity type: paragraph, bundle: `grid_item_node_list`, field name: `field_text`

However I can't use the same deletion approach for that field as it is in use for new content (on different paragraph bundles).

In exported config, no files contain `grid_item_node_list` and no files have that in their name. Yet when I grep the database I find :

`cache_config.cid` contains 2:

- `field.field.paragraph.grid_item_node_list.field_page_ref`
- `field.field.paragraph.grid_item_node_list.field_text`

And `cache_default.data` also contains `grid_item_node_list`  as does `cache_discovery.data` and `key_value.value` (for name: `paragraph`).

I don't understand why (a) these config aren't exported, and (b) why the cache-related ones aren't cleared on `drush cr`.